# php login can't redirect

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a log-in page, but after I insert the correct username and password it went to the checkLogin.php and says You are not allowed to execute this file directly instead of redirect. I can't find where did I make the mistake.

```
<?php
// checkLogin.php
session_start(); // Start a new session
require('connect.php'); // Holds all of our database connection information
// Get the data passed from the form
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$sql = "Select 
supplier_id as id,
supplier_lastname as lastname,
supplier_firstname as firstname,
supplier_email as email ,
supplier_phone as phone,
'Supplier' as entity_name
FROM suppliers 
WHERE suppliers.supplier_id = '$username' AND suppliers.supplier_pw = '$password'
union all
SELECT
customer_id as id,
customer_lastname as lastname,
customer_firstname as firstname,
customer_email as email,
customer_phone as phone,
'Customer' as entity_name 
FROM customers
WHERE customers.customer_id = '$username' AND customers.customer_pw = '$password';
";
$result = mysqli_query($sql) or die ( mysqli_error() );
$count = 0;
$line= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
while ($line) {
     $count++;
     $info = $line[5];
}
if ($count == 1 && $info='Supplier') {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "true";
    $_SESSION['username'] = $line['id'];
    header("Location: application/view_orders.php"); 
}
elseif ($count == 1 && $info='Customer') {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "true";
    $_SESSION['username'] = $line['id'];
    header("Location: application/orderForm.php");
}
else {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "false";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Log-In failed! Please check your username or password again.'); window.location.href='http://oncommercetrend.com/'</script>";
}
?>
```

And here is my form:

```
<form class="login active" action="checkLogin.php">
                    <h3>Login</h3>
                    <div>
                        <label>Username:</label>
                        <input name="user"type="text" />
                        <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Password: <!--<a href="forgot_password.html" rel="forgot_password" class="forgot linkform">Forgot your password?</a>--></label>
                        <input name="password" type="password" />
                        <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom">
                        <div class="remember"><input type="checkbox" /><span>Keep me logged in</span></div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
                        <a href="register.html" rel="register" class="linkform">You don't have an account yet? Register here</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Here is DB connection:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish a DB connection');
mysqli_select_db($db_database,$link);
```

Comment: Your form doesn't have a post method. Modify to `<form class="login active" action="checkLogin.php" method="post">` see if that makes it kick in. Form defaults to a GET method if omitted. You can also get rid of `</input>`, that's invalid for inputs.

Comment: I just put the method inside of my form and get rid of `</input>` but it still doesn't work. After click log-in, it went to checkLogin.php and says You are not allowed to execute this file directly

Comment: You should add `exit;` after all your headers. That is often a problem.

Comment: You also have quotes around `'Supplier' as entity_name` remove them. and `'Customer' as entity_name` could be a contributing factor.

Comment: By the way, is your form and PHP/SQL inside the same file or seperate files?

Comment: Oh, you're missing the DB connection variable to your query. `mysqli_query($sql)` - do `mysqli_query($con,$sql)` for example if `$con` is your variable for example.

Comment: You also need to be DB parameter to `mysqli_error()` - `mysqli_error($con)` I'm using `$con` because I don't know what or how you're using for it.

Comment: hmmm I must do it if I include the connect.php?

Comment: Yes, as per PHP.net `$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));` is that what you have now or similar? You need to post your DB connection for me to know for sure, while replacing actual credentials with `xxx`.

Comment: I just update the DB connection.

Comment: +1 Glad to see someone's not mixing the `MySQL` and `MySQLi` libraries as many new users do.

Comment: o wait... I think I found the problem

Comment: @Joseph what is the problem?

Comment: I used the wrong connection.php script... I upload the wrong one on my server lmao

Comment: it now giving me 500 error after log-in... god

Comment: Well, you have the option. That I post an answer with my already given comments that were part of the problem or you can delete your question. Otherwise, it will remain as unanswered. @Joseph

Comment: well I still have problem with it; it's showing 500 error but I'm not sure if it's related to the title. Should I ask another question and close this one?

Comment: Check your logs, it's a server related error.

Comment: You need to change your DB code to this `$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish a DB connection');
mysqli_select_db($link, $db_database);` and you need to define `db_database` to the database name you're using, or just use `$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass, $db_database) or die('Unable to establish a DB connection');`

Comment: interesting, if I changed to the first one it's giving me 500 error. If I changed to the second one it says no database selected.

Comment: see my answer below, it's easier than commenting lol

Comment: So @Joseph how are you making out?

Comment: not really... still working on it. Keep having 500 error. I'm trying to find other way to solve it. thanks for the help bud :D

Comment: You're welcome. If you have access to error logs, see if there's anything in there that could help you. In many cases it will.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to show you in graphic form, rather than commenting back and forth.

Your form doesn't have a post method.

Modify to

```
<form class="login active" action="checkLogin.php" method="post">
```

Form defaults to a GET method if omitted.

You should add `exit;` after all your headers.

You need to change your DB code to this and change to your actual settings/credentials:

```
$db_host = "yourhost";
$db_user = "user";
$db_pass = "password";
$db_database = "database_name";

$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_database) 
        or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

change this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($sql) or die ( mysqli_error() );
```

to this (passing DB connection parameter first)

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die ( mysqli_error($link) );
```